# Codemagic post-clone script failed on base64 command not found

Tags: flutter, continuous-integration, codemagic

I'm trying to decode environment variable value on Codemagic via custom script and get the next error:

```
post-clone script failed on base64 decode. The command could not be found
```

The script what I use:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo $ANDROID_FIREBASE_JSON | base64 --decode > $FCI_BUILD_DIR/android/app/google-services.json
echo $IOS_FIREBASE_JSON | base64 --decode > $FCI_BUILD_DIR/ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that you copy-pasted the script with some Unicode characters that the browser doesn't render. Just remove the space between the `base64` command and the `--decode` option and then add it back.

You can find additional information in this article: https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-load-firebase-config-in-codemagic-with-environment-variables-e36e0378b7e6